# Access SQL Calculating inventory at certain date, stock results doubling when ordered twice

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL Query which shows the inventory status before any orders in or out:

```
SELECT Query3.Products.ID, Query3.ProductName, Query3.StandardCost, Query3.OnHand,
  Nz(Sum([OrderJoin.Quantity]),0) AS Outgoing, Nz(Sum([Query1.Quantity]),0) AS Incoming,
  [OnHand]+[Outgoing]-[Incoming] AS OnHandAfter, [StandardCost]*[OnHandAfter] AS TotalCost
FROM Query3
GROUP BY Query3.Products.ID, Query3.ProductName, Query3.StandardCost, Query3.OnHand;
```

And then I've tried to filter it so it accepts a user-inputted date to back-track stock status to:

```
SELECT Q1.Products.ID, 
 Q1.ProductName, 
 Q1.StandardCost, 
 Q1.OnHand, 
 SUM([Q1.OnHand] + [Q2_sub.Outgoing] - [Q3_sub.Incoming]) AS OnHandAfter, 
 ([Q1.StandardCost] * [OnHandAfter]) AS TotalCost
FROM (
 Query3 AS Q1 
      LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT Q2.Products.ID, 
                Q2.ProductName, 
                Q2.StandardCost, 
                Q2.OnHand, 
                NZ(Sum([OrderJoin.Quantity]), 0) AS Outgoing 
           FROM Query3 AS Q2 
           WHERE (
                     (
                         (ShippedDate) > [Enter End Date]
                         OR (ShippedDate) IS NULL
                         )
                     )
           GROUP BY Q2.Products.ID, 
                Q2.ProductName, 
                Q2.StandardCost, 
                Q2.OnHand)  AS Q2_Sub ON Q1.Products.ID = Q2_Sub.ID) 
      LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT Q3.Products.ID, 
                     Q3.ProductName, 
                     Q3.StandardCost, 
                     Q3.OnHand, 
                     NZ(Sum([Query1.Quantity]), 0) AS Incoming
                FROM Query3 AS Q3 
                WHERE (
                     (
                         (DateReceived) > [Enter End Date]
                         OR (DateReceived) IS NULL
                      )
                 ) 
                GROUP BY Q3.Products.ID, 
                     Q3.ProductName, 
                     Q3.StandardCost, 
                     Q3.OnHand)  AS Q3_Sub ON Q1.Products.ID = Q3_Sub.ID
GROUP BY Q1.Products.ID, Q1.ProductName, Q1.StandardCost, Q1.OnHand;
```

**It comes to mostly correct results, but there are some that are completely off,**

**EDIT:**

**After looking into it, it appears some are doubling up in the Outgoing/Incoming columns**

**EDIT EDIT:**

**The thing the products that are doubling up have in common are they've all been ordered on two occasions. (i.e. the coffee has been ordered once for 25 and once for 5, but comes up as 60.) How do I fix it from counting them both twice?**

**Also a couple such as Crab Meat now seem to be counting cumulatively, i.e. when I first ran it it came up as 370 OnHandAfter, and now it's coming up as 416 after adding 46 again**

What it should be

```
| ID | Product Name | Standard Cost | On Hand | Outgoing | Incoming | OnHandAfter | TotalCost |
| 14 | Crab Meat    | £13.80        | 185     | 23       | 0        | 208         | £2,870.40
```

What it comes to

```
| ID | Product Name | Standard Cost | On Hand | Outgoing | Incoming | OnHandAfter | TotalCost
| 14 | Crab Meat    | £13.80        | 185     | 46       | 0        | 370         | £5,106.00
```

---

What it should be

```
| ID | Product Name | Standard Cost | On Hand | Outgoing | Incoming | OnHandAfter | TotalCost |
| 16 | Coffee       | £34.50        | 150     | 30       | 152      | 28          | £966.00
```

What it comes to

```
| ID | Product Name | Standard Cost | On Hand | Outgoing | Incoming | OnHandAfter | TotalCost
| 16 | Coffee       | £34.50        | 150     | 60       | 304      | 46          | £1,587.00
```

Comment: what happens if you try using `select distinct`?

Comment: @LiamH No change, the results come out in one row, just the value doubles when it's been ordered on more than one occassion

Answer (score 0):

As you use Pound, you're probably from the UK, thus having dates formatted as *dd/mm/yyyy*.

So, in your query, you may have to specify `[Enter End Date]` as a Parameter of data type Date and - as the date fields can be Null - take care of that, like replacing this:

```
(ShippedDate) > [Enter End Date]
OR (ShippedDate) IS NULL
```

with:

```
Nz([ShippedDate], #9999/12/31#) > [Enter End Date]
```

Comment: Ok thank you for that, it looks like in Access the date for me automatically comes as DD/MM/YYYY, but I didn't even think of that